# how to print two matching word in single line using awk throughout the file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a log file with below format.

Resetid daldiodu490284jfslfj

Department IT

Day Friday

Time 33.0mmsec

EndTime 50.0mmsec

EOF

---

Resetid fjsoifuoieru9003948

Department IT

Day Tuesday

Time 43.0mmsec

EndTime 90.0mmsec

EOF

---

I want O/p matching **Resetid** and **Time** only like below.

Resetid daldiodu490284jfslfj Time 33.0mmsec

Resetid fjsoifuoieru9003948 Time 43.0mmsec

I am using = awk '/Resetid/{ RESETID=$0; next } /Time/{ print RESETID "," $0 }'
but getting wrong o/p. please help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please wrap your samples into CODE TAGS in your post.

Comment: got the answer awk '/Resetid/{RESETID=$0; next} /^Time/{ print RESETID " " $0}' -- was missing starting cap ^

Answer (score 0):

`/Time/` also matches "End**Time**". Use a carat, `^`, to say it has to start with "Time". Also, the `next` seems unnecessary.

```
awk '/Resetid/{ RESETID=$0 } /^Time/{ print RESETID " " $0 }'
```

output:

```
Resetid daldiodu490284jfslfj Time 33.0mmsec
Resetid fjsoifuoieru9003948 Time 43.0mmsec
```